# BadImageFormatException when loading 32 bit DLL, target is x86

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, 32bit-64bit, badimageformatexception

I have a DLL (FreeType) which is certainly 32-bit (header: IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386).

I want to use it from C# code, using DllImport.

Target of my application is x86, IntPtr.Size is 4, process is 32-bit.

But I get BadImageFormatException (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B). What can be wrong?

Of course I use 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Voting to close as 'not a real question' -- the basis for the question was a misunderstanding; the OP found the DLL in question was loading correctly

Answer (score 48):

From what I understand, an assembly specifically built for x86 and running in a 64-bit operating system can only load libraries built for x86 or a BadImageFormatException will be thrown. In a 64-bit OS, an assembly built for Any CPU or x64 will throw the same exception when trying to load an x86 library.

So, assuming nothing incredibly weird is going on, I would ensure that you've set your application to build as x86 by opening the project properties and clicking on the Build tab. Ensure 'Platform Target' is set as 'x86' and not Any CPU.

Alternatively, you could try to find a 64-bit version of the DLL for testing purposes.

Comment: I am 100% sure that my C# app is 32-bit. I even used CORFLAGS to check it:

Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 3
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 1
Signed    : 0

Comment: @Eric Smith I was having the same issue...this fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, and the same thing happens the other way around. For example, if a 64-bit app attempts to load a 32-bit DLL.

Answer (score 9):

Recompile the dll with the option  "Any CPU" in Build -> Platform.

[image]

Comment: Any CPU is not in the list for me.

Answer (score 7):

OK, seems like a false alert. It was not related to bitness, there was just other DLL missing that freetype depends on. However error messages could be more helpful.

Comment: This half solved my problem with BadImageFormatException - I forgot to copy over the dependent DLLs. Unfortunately now I get DllNotFoundException on the original DLL...

Comment: @jarmond make sure you built Release version (not Debug)

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error when calling a 64-bit C Dll from C#. I had to manually change C# `Properties->Build->Platform target` from `Any Cpu` to `x64`. Apparently `Any Cpu` is sometimes NoCpu.

Answer (score 4):

Besides, for web-application needs resolve to run 32-Bit Applications in IIS 7. See http://www.fishofprey.com/2009/04/badimageformatexception-in-iis-70-on-64.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error.
I could solve it by adding the ucrtbase.dll or ucrtbased.dll for debug as well as the vcruntime140.dll or vcruntime140d.dll for debug into the directory of the executable. 
I think the 140 depends on the version number of Visual Studio you are using.

ucrtbase.dll usually lies in `C:\Windows\System32`.
vcruntime140.dll lies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\vcruntime140.dll`

You can find more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the common cause of this exception has changed in the 8 years since the question was first asked. On my setup using VS 2017 I found that unchecking "Prefer 32-bit" solved the issue:

[Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" in the Build options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F642G.png)

This made my 64-bit DLL built from C++ load correctly. Conversely, checking this option should make 32-bit DLLs load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a native application/DLL something with Visual Studio, it gains a dependency on the "redistributable" package for that version of Visual Studio. That contains DLLs like `msvcr100.dll` and `msvcp100.dll` (for various values of 100).

In my case, I had seen those DLLs in the target machine's `Windows/system32` directory, so I thought all was well. It turns out that those DLLs were x64! I have no idea why a directory called `system32` contains 64-bit DLLs.  So I searched my Visual Studio 2010 directory for everything named `msvc*.dll`, and found x86 versions of `msvcr100.dll` and `msvcp100.dll`.  I copied those to the target machine (in a place accessible from my program's path) and all was well.

I hope this helps someone else confronted with Microsoft's sheer madness.

Answer (score 1):

you use Properties in C# project, and change "Platform target" to x64.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Dad.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try check the option "Properties" -> "Build" -> "Allow unsafe code".

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the dependents of the DLL, since one of the dependents may use a 64 bit DLL which makes it incompatible with your project.
visual studio -> tools -> command line -> powershell

`dumpbin /dependents your_dll_file.dll`
and check these dll's and find out which one is actually not the same with your dll.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Exception in MS Visual C# Express 2010. I checked all build .dll and .exe files with Dependency Walker and MiTeC EXE Explorer, everything was build for 32bit!

In the end, it was the following line missing in my .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'MY_CONFIG|x86'">
    ...
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

I don't know why it was missing ... I guess MS Visual C# Express 2010 is not bugfree ;)