# Calling a dll created in VB6 from F#

Tags: f#, interop, f#-3.0

I am trying to call a dll file created in vb6 from F#. I have written the following dll.

```basic
Public Function AddTwoNumbers(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
    AddTwoNumbers = a + b
End Function
```

Now I want to call it in my F# program, I wrote this code

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module InteropWithNative =
   [<DllImport(@"C:\add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]  
   void AddTwoNumbers(int, int)

InteropWithNative.AddTwoNumbers(3,4)

let result = AddTwoNumbers_ 2.0 3.0
```

It gives me errors and doesn't recognize the function.

Comment: Please at least state the errors

Comment: Unexpected keyword 'void' in implementation file                                 Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in definition

Comment: Please suggest me a better way to call a dll funtion through F# as well

Comment: Seems to (at least) miss the [extern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393785.aspx) before `void` (which shouldn't be `void` but `int` because the VB code is a Function not a Sub

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to create a library in age-old VB6? Better to either convert any existing VB6 to VB.NET so that you can call the methods directly, or switch to another language if you need native code.

Comment: Define the EntryPoint="AddTwoNumbers" in [<DllImport(@"C:\add.dll", EntryPoint="AddTwoNumbers", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]

Comment: @Abel > we have a project in vb6 and want to convert it to F#. Our First approach is to convert it to dll and call it from the F#. Later we will convert the whole vb6 project to F#.

Comment: @Functional_S > I tried the entry point method, but it never works. Can you paste here a running code as an example.

Answer (score 2):

A working interop example with an EntryPoint

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices // for DllImport

module KernelInterop = 
    [<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="Beep")>]
    extern void Beep( int frequency, int duration )

KernelInterop.Beep  // val Beep : int * int -> unit
KernelInterop.Beep(440, 1000)
```

Comment: @Funtional_S >   The above code works well, and I played it. But how can I use it for the question,                                                              open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module InteropWithNative =
   [<DllImport(@"C:\add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]  
   void AddTwoNumbers(int, int)

InteropWithNative.AddTwoNumbers(3,4)

let result = AddTwoNumbers_ 2.0 3.0

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ConsoleApplication32.exe

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Comment: This may help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728560/badimageformatexception-when-loading-32-bit-dll-target-is-x86]

Comment: :>  I read the article. It focuses only on changing the compiler mode from x64 to x84. Afterwards, I tried to run the code and still get the same error. Can you please test it on your system to see..  
module InteropWithNative =
    [<DllImport(@"C:\add.dll", EntryPoint="AddTwoNumbers",  CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern int32 AddTwoNumbers(int32 a, int32 b)
let result = InteropWithNative.AddTwoNumbers(2,5)
printf "Result is: %d" result