# Bizarre System.BadImageFormatException when trying to import C++ dll into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

Here is the relevent C# bits

**KrautVK.cs**

```
internal static class KrautVK{
    [DllImport("lib\\krautvk", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "init")]
    internal static extern int Init(int width, int height, string title, bool fullscreen);

    [DllImport("lib\\krautvk", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "windowShouldClose")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool WindowShouldClose();

    [DllImport("lib\\krautvk", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "pollEvents")]
    internal static extern void PollEvents();

    [DllImport("lib\\krautvk", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "terminate")]
    internal static extern void Terminate();
}
```

Here is the (relevant) C++ code:

**KrautVK.h**

```
#ifndef KRAUTVK_H_
#define KRAUTVK_H_

#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

**...**

```
EXPORT int init(int w, int h, char *title, int f);

EXPORT int windowShouldClose();

EXPORT void pollEvents();

EXPORT void terminate();
```

I am very much aware that `System.BadImageFormatException` can be thrown by DllImport if there's a build format mismatch (ie calling a 32 bit dll from a 64 bit application). However, this is not the case. Both are built and target the same CPU.

After doing some troubleshooting, I found that it's caused solely by the `iostream` and `vector` includes. By removing those includes, the error goes away and the calls work. In fact, I didn't have any problems until I started implementing code that needed those includes. However, I need those includes, and the better part of a day's worth of research has turned up no documentation or explanation for this bizarre behavior, and many examples in fact use `iostream`.

I'm using both Jetbrains Rider and Clion, if that is relevent.

Comment: *Both are built and target the same CPU* -- How did you determine this, i.e. what you finally end up with are actually 32-bit binaries?  Also, [the answers here do not just talk about "bitness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728560/badimageformatexception-when-loading-32-bit-dll-target-is-x86)

Comment: For one, build targets are clearly observable in both IDE's I develop with, and, as an added measure, I used dumpbin to examine the file header of the dll. Also, as I already said in my question, removing includes of `iostream` and `vector` somehow the error goes away. That has nothing to do with build targets.

Comment: I am aware that bitness is not the only cause of `System.BadImageFormatException`, and didn't intend to imply such. Clearly it's related to those includes, but I have not found documentation or leads as to what the problem actually is.

Comment: Why not see if it has anything to do with using the runtime library?  Using `vector` and `iostream` requires usage of the correct runtime library.  That is one of the other answers given at the link.

Comment: Those answers were relating the fact that building a native dll in Visual Studio necessitates having VS runtime libraries attached, However I'm using Clion, specifically the MingW64 toolchain. Do I need to include some kind of dll for that runtime, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: What are the dependencies for your C++ DLL? (I use Dependency Walker).  Are any of them the Visual C++ runtime?  If there are missing DLL's, the easiest thing is to place them in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: Got it. No VC dependencies (as expected) but I didn't realize Mingw64 has some of it's own dependency requirements. I got it all sorted out in dependency walker. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dependency Walker, I was missing 3 dll's:

- libstdc++-6.dll
- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
- and libwinpthread-1.dll

They are the required runtime libraries if you use the MingW environment. Dropping those into the executable folder did the trick. They can be found in `{Your MingW/MingW64 installation folder}\bin`

Comment: That was not the real problem, a missing DLL cannot cause a BadImageFormatException.  You need to find the *other* copy (or copies) of those DLLs to get your machine fixed.  Typically accidentally found through a messed-up PATH environment variable or a stray copy in the OS directory.  Use the *where* command first.

Comment: My PATH is set up for C++ development, But I'm treating it as release, ie most users do not have MingW64 with PATH pointing at the provided runtimes, so I need to provide those dll's. Hence why testing in the executable works but accessing bindings from it as a dll was failing. More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code.

Comment: Also it seems that there are cases where a missing DLL can cause a BadImageFormatException. See here for another case example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728560/badimageformatexception-when-loading-32-bit-dll-target-is-x86