# Loading C# assembly from MemoryStream: Bad IL format. How to correctly load fully in-memory assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dllimport, asp.net-core-2.1

Using **.NET Core 2.1** and **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 2.10.0** to *dynamically* compile to assembly and keep it *in-memory*. Then trying to load this assembly via `AssemblyLoadContext` getting

> Bad IL format

How to correctly load fully *in-memory* assembly?
What is the reason of this exception?
I am missing to specify some *metadata* to the in-memory assembly?
What are other most common cases then **Bad IL format** could occur?

This code example bellow produces the exception:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("a")
                    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
                    .AddReferences(
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location))
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
                    @"

public static class C
{
    public static int M(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}

                    "));

                var results = compilation.Emit(stream);
                //results.Success is true here
                var context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
                Assembly a = context.LoadFromStream(stream);//<--Exception here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Runtime exception details:

```
System.BadImageFormatException
  HResult=0x8007000B
  Message=Bad IL format.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, IntPtr ptrAssemblyArray, Int32 iAssemblyArrayLen, IntPtr ptrSymbols, Int32 iSymbolArrayLen, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(Stream assembly, Stream assemblySymbols)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\repos\sketches\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 37
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: You class doesn't appear to be defined inside a namespace. Could that be it?

Comment: @MartinCostello - it's perfectly valid to write a class without a `namespace`. And if that were the problem, you'd expect compilation, not loading, to raise a stink about it.

Comment: what is the target cpu - any?, 64, 86?

Comment: @Martin Costello Tested this case - no. Then compilation emit files and I try to load assembly by path it works, but I need fully in-memory solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728678/703163

Comment: @JohnB Target CPU: Any; Current OS: Win10 x64

Comment: try targeting the specific cpu and see what happens

Comment: With memory stream you have after filling set the position to zero before reading.  Otherwise, you do not get any data since you are at the end of stream.

Comment: @JohnB x64 - equal to "Any CPU". x86 - program shutdowns after 1-2s without invoking Main.

Comment: @jdweng Yes it worked. Needed to set `stream.Position = 0;` before invoking `context.LoadFromStream(...)`

Comment: A note to anyone else seeing this error: remember to check the EmitResult returned by the Emit() method for any compilation errors.